# Modifying Sublime Text 3 default <script> tag

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

Using autocomplete, the default  tag for Sublime Text 3 is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How do I modify it, so that the default autocomplete shows **only**:

```
<script></script>
```

Note: I have PackageResourceViewer installed..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes you're running the latest version of Sublime Text 3. From the command palette, select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`, scroll down to HTML, then select `html_completions.py`. Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the menu. Now, scroll down to line 296, which should read:

```py
('script\tTag', 'script${2: type=\"${1:text/javascript}\"}>$0</script>'),
```

Simply change that to:

```py
('script\tTag', 'script>$0</script>'),
```

and save the file. You should now be all set.

Comment: Don't these changes get lost with every new version of Sublime Text?

Comment: @idleberg No, they won't. When you alter and save a file using PackageResourceViewer, instead of altering the original `.sublime-package` archive, it creates an identically-named folder in `Packages` and stores the altered file(s) there. So, in this case, saving the altered file will automatically create `Packages/HTML/html_completions.py`. Since files in `Packages` are loaded *after* the correspondingly-named files in `.sublime-package` archives, they will override them. In ST3, folders in `Packages` are not overwritten on upgrade, unless the plugin has a `.no-sublime-package` file.

Comment: @MattDMo Cool, didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> followed by Backspace to delete the type? If this is to tedious for you, you can simply create your own snippet:

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
<script>$1</script>
]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>script</tabTrigger>
  <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```